# Properties of square integrability?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I'm reading [this book](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718690) on shape optimization and (for the first time) in p. 8. the author defines a "state variational inequality" version of a simple shape optimization problem

$$u_\alpha \in K(\alpha): \int_0^{\alpha} u_{\alpha}'(v'-u_{\alpha}')dx ≥ \int_0^{\alpha} 2(v-u_{\alpha})dx \space \forall v \in K(\alpha)$$

where

$$K(\alpha)= \{ v \in H^1(]0, \alpha[) \space | \space v(0)=0, v(\alpha)≤1\} \space \alpha \in U^{ad}$$

Here $H^k(\Omega)$ is "the set of functions whose generalized derivatives up to order $k \in \{0\} \cup \mathbb{N}$ are square integrable in $\Omega$".

Now, why is square integrable here as a property? What makes it desirable?

Answer (score 1):

That first integral is equal to
$$\int_0^\alpha u_\alpha'v' \,dx - \int_0^\alpha u_\alpha'^2 \,dx$$
Because of that second term, in order for the integral to exist when, say, $v\equiv 0$, we need $u_\alpha '$ to be square integrable. Even for the first term, we need $u_\alpha'$ and $v'$ to be square integrable in order for the integral to exist.

Comment: But I assume it's possible that one could require square integrability without having (as it now happens to be) the square integrability readable directly in the equation. Also, how do you infer that the first term forces $u_{\alpha}'$ and $v'$ square integrable?

Comment: In general, square integrability (in my experience) is usually just used if integrating a product/square is in a definition, or if it's expected to be used. As for your second question, we need square intrgability for the first term because, for example, we might have $u_\alpha' = v'$. Conversely, the product of square integrable functions is integrable, so we're good.